# want to windows based python application on android

Tags: android, python, windows

I have an GUI based Python application which is developed using Python-2.7, pygtk, numpy & scipy on windows. Is there any way to use this software on android platform?

I am also working on its linux version.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, although you can run `python` on an Android device (see https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/ for more information) you can't use every package such as `pygtk` as it is a windowing system written for desktop and Android uses a different system.

The best you can do is to leave the application logic in `python` and rewrite the user interface using `html` (more on how can you create a UI with sl4a can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/UsingWebView))

Comment: html is not the only option, it would also be possible to write the ui with [kivy](http://kivy.org/#home). kivy's python-for-android project can also compile numpy for android, but not scipy - I think replacing the scipy parts would be necessary.